# When 觉得 is used with 怎么样, what is the noun subject?

Tags: grammar

怎么样 is normally used with a noun subject before it, to mean "how is subject?"

But when you ask an opinion, the structure is
你觉得 + Topic + 怎么样 ?

That confuses me, since I'm not how 你觉得 + Topic is a noun?

觉得 means to feel or to think.

Is 你觉得 + Topic a noun because it's an action? Is it like asking, how is the action of thinking about Topic?

Or can 觉得 be translated into "thoughts of" which can also make "你觉得 + Topic" a noun.

Answer (score 1):

你觉得怎么样? = How do you feel? Which is a common form of conservation to express care, or to inquire about others' opinions about something, the subject topic is often obvious to both parties without needing to address it, as it is redundant.

- A friend has twisted his ankle, out of concern, you might simply ask "你(的腳踝)觉得怎么样?" Since the injury is obvious to both of you, so the subject topic "腳踝" is not required to be included in the question.
- You and your girlfriend in a shopping center, she picked up one of the bags on display and asked "(這個包包)你觉得怎么样?" Since she was asking your opinion on something quite obvious to both of you, so the subject topic "這個包包" is a redundant element.

However, you should always include the subject topic if the question is about something unclear to the other person, or in writing, to avoid confusion, otherwise, the reaction of others will be "你觉得**什麽東西**怎么样?"